# Blend alpha of overlapped area without adding alpha

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas, android-paint

I don't know if what I'm asking is possible.
I've a `Paint` with `Color.BLACK` with 0.2f of alpha and two objects:

[image]

They both use the same `Paint`. I've also tested with 2 different `Paint` objects changing only the `PorterDuffXfermode` but I had no success. What I want is to avoid the overlapped areas to become darker, in other words, I don't want them to "add" their alpha channels. I want the same alpha for all the objects (even when they overlap). Is it possible? How can I achieve it?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single path for both objects.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(..
path.lineTo(..
path.addCircle(...
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

But while typing this, I remembered that this works only if both objects have same style - either both fill or both stroke or both fill&stroke

With two different paint objects, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: In this case they share the same Paint object so it works perfectly! addCircle > addArc > drawPath. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Although this answers my question, if I want to animate the "spot" over the "circular" path, this approach has a little problem, the paths aren't removed/cleared. This will leave a trace.